# String-Conversion: MBCS <-> UNICODE with multiple \0 within

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, msdn, multibyte-functions

I am trying to convert a std::string Buffer - containing data from a bitmap file - to std::wstring.

I am using `MultiByteToWideChar`, but that does not work, because the  function stops after it encounters the first `'\0'`-character. Seems like it interprets it as the end of the string.

When i dont pass -1 as the length-parameter, but the real length of the data in the std::string-Buffer, it messes the Unicode-String up with characters that definetly not appeared at that position in the original string...

Do I have to write my own conversion function?
Or maybe shall i keep the data as a casual char-array, because the special-symbols will be converted incorrectly?

With regards

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about what you're trying to do.  Are you saying that you have the raw bits from a bitmap (image) file stored in a std::string?  If so, then you probably DON'T want to do this, as the data that you have is not string (character/glpyh) data.  The MBCS->UNICODE conversion simply doesn't make sense here.  What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I wrote a function to send data over a socket. That function takes a std::wstring as a parameter... If i dont get the conversion, i need to rewrite this function to take a char* and the length of the buffer or something like this, which i dont really want... but if thats anything thats left to me...

Comment: Rewrite the function, it is completely unsuitable to send binary data.

Comment: thx... plz post it as answer, so i can rate it

Comment: @Incubbus - Your "function to send data over a socket" needs to be reworked.  As your question is tagged C++, consider providing overloads that support properly marhsalling string, wstring, and binary data.

Comment: Ok, so im going to provide an overloaded version for raw data...

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, **many** things that will fail with this approach. Among other things, extra bytes may be added to your data without your realizing it.

It's odd that your only option takes a `std::wstring()`. If this is a home-grown library, you should take the trouble to write a new function. If it's not, make sure there's nothing more suitable before writing your own.